# I am able to detect browsing, but I want additional information

Tags: javascript

I'm making a kind of Browser Detection library (I know user agent sniffing isn't ideal). I found a pretty useful snippet on quirksmode.org that looked something like this:

```
var $browser = {
    init: function () {
        this.name = this.searchString(this.dataName) || "An unknown browser";

        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
    },

searchString: function (data) {

    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

        var dataString = data[i].string;

        var dataProp = data[i].prop;

        this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;

        if (dataString) {
            if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                return data[i].identity;
        }

        else if (dataProp) {
            return data[i].identity;
        }
    }
},

searchVersion: function (dataString) {
    var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
    if (index == -1) return;
    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
},

dataName: [
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Chrome",
        identity: "Chrome"
    },
    {   string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "OmniWeb",
        versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
        identity: "OmniWeb"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "Apple",
        identity: "Safari",
        versionSearch: "Version"
    },
    {
        prop: window.opera,
        identity: "Opera",
        versionSearch: "Version"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "iCab",
        identity: "iCab"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "KDE",
        identity: "Konqueror"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Firefox",
        identity: "Firefox"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "Camino",
        identity: "Camino"
    },
    {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Netscape",
        identity: "Netscape"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "MSIE",
        identity: "Internet Explorer",
        versionSearch: "MSIE"
    },
    {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Mozilla",
        identity: "Netscape",
        versionSearch: "Mozilla"
    }
]
};
$browser.init();
```

So now I can do something like

```
alert($browser.name + $browser.version);
```

But I also want to be able to do $browser.author, $browser.prefix and $browser.engine.
Anyone know how I could do this? I know I could do

```
 if($browser.name == "Chrome"){ var engine = "WebKit" }
```

But I don't want just "engine", I want "$browser.engine"

### EDIT


Ok, look guys, as I said before **I know user agent sniffing isn't ideal**. And I'm not basing my entire project on this. This is just a short little module on a bigger JS file. This is just a handy $browser module. I know feature detection is **way** better than ua sniffing, and I use modernizr way more than I do jQuery browser object, or Dojo "has". In fact I never use those.
And I know that stackoverflow typically isn't a tutoring website (well, isn't a tutoring website rather), but I was kinda hoping just to find out a quick little way to add extra information in each object manually. I've tried many ways and kept getting errors or fails.

Comment: You should never even consider browser sniffing, you should always detect features.

Comment: Why?  What do you hope to achieve with browser detection?  If that is from the code base I _think_ it is, there should be a warning on the page saying **never do this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these links:

- [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)
- [DetectRight](http://www.detectright.com/)
- [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/)
- [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
- [MDBF](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/)

Keep in mind though that you shouldn't generally use this information *instead* of feature detection (unless you have to - like for some mobile browsers where you can't do proper feature detection which is probably not aplicable here since you're doing it in JavaScript anyway).

For proper feature detection use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) and be as [future friendly](http://futurefriend.ly/) as you possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Map `browser` is effectively grouped into engines, as the "safari" value is deprecated and the "webkit" value is now preferred.

But you should use jQuery.support anyway.